# Connecting to a database without explicitly openning a connection

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I was helping a friend who is still in college with her business homework. The class teaches VB.NET and ADO.NET (really poorly of course). I only have brief experience with ADO.NET via a legacy application I support at work.

The page she was trying to implement was very simple: A form with inputs for `username`, `password` and a `submit` button. There were some functionality issues, but while looking through the code, I noticed something strange. Here is the code she used at the top of the page to set up the connection

```
Public Shared Con As New SqlConnection("Data Source = asdfa; Initial Catalog= asdf; Persist Security Info = True; User ID= dfasdf; Password = asdf")
Public Shared strSQLStatement As String
Public Shared strSQLStatementCmd As String
Public Shared daActivity As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQLStatement, Con)
Public Shared dsActivity As New DataSet
```

I did not see anything to the sound of `con.open()` as I have expected. From my knowledge, ADO.NET requires such a command to initially establish a connection. I questioned her about this and she mentioned that she has never used an `open()` command to establish a connection in any of her other homeworks, which she received full credit for. Is there something in this code that automagically opens the connection for me?

Maybe my understanding of ADO.NET is construed. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but the language is purely used to connecting to databases and is done so in this fashion

```
Set up connection string
Open connection
Create sql strings, such as command = "select * from table1"
Tell the open connection to run that sql
Close Connection
```

Does that seem about right? Help me help her.

Thanks

Comment: Nothing in what you've posted that requires the connection to be open. Where's the code for using it. e.g. dsActivity.Fill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SqlDataAdapter` will automatically open and close the connection for you.

> The Fill method retrieves rows from the data source using the SELECT
>   statement specified by an associated SelectCommand property. The
>   connection object associated with the SELECT statement must be valid,
>   **but it does not need to be open**. If the connection is closed before
>   Fill is called, it is opened to retrieve data, then closed. If the
>   connection is open before Fill is called, it remains open.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am reading through the documentation of SqlDataAdapter now. When that command is run, the query isn't actually being executed right? I would need to use `fill`. Is it possible to change the sql command string associated with that object? I apologize, as I would normally just try this myself, but do not have access to this sort of environment readily available at this time.

Comment: `Fill` will execute the `SelectCommand` which you can modify if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Dim MovingDA As New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlbyworknum, myConnection)
  MovingDA.Fill(MovingDT)

just you use new at declraing DA and pass sql and you connection it will be opend and run